# matplotlib won't install in python 3.8

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.8

So it looks like its is trying to build it from source because there isn't a prebuilt package for it in python 3.8. The issue is zlib appears to be a dependency of Pillow which matplotlib needs. Pillow is already installed, but the installation for matplotlib seems to be doing it from scratch. The entire error is below, but I replaced part of the file paths with '...' and deleted a huge list of files to make it easier to read.

```
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\pip-install-see1c21m\pillow\setup.py", line 995, in <module>
    setup(
  File "...\autoscript\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  -------(deleted a huge list of files to make it easy to read)---------     
  File "...\pip-install-see1c21m\pillow\setup.py", line 810, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\pip-install-see1c21m\pillow\setup.py", line 1015, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html



----------------------------------------
```

Command "...\autoscript\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='...\pip-install-see1c21m\pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(co
de, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record ...\pip-record-7sa9h0d8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --
install-headers ...\autoscript\include\site\python3.8\pillow" failed with error code 1 in ...\pip-install-see1c21m\pillow\

Anyway I would like to not have to figure out zib on windows and make sure its accessible within my python virtual environment. Any help is appreciate ty!

Comment: how did you install pillow? are you using multiple environments? python 3.8 is pretty old already. what's blocking you from upgrading? what command did you invoke to produce this error? would conda or mamba be an option?

Comment: pillow was installed and updated with pip, so I am not sure why it installs from source. I did this all within the same virtual environment. I decided to just delete python entirely, my IDE, install the latest python 10 and it all seems to work.